# mounting and using a device with no partitions?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

It has always been my understanding that to use a disk or other storage device, it needs to have a partition which can then be mounted and used. Is this wrong? I inserted an nvme device in the machine and using the 'disks' gui utility chose ext4 and successfully mounted it to /mnt/nvme. My current situation:

`lsblk` returns
`nvme0n1 259:0    0 465,8G  0 disk /mnt/nvme` with no tree under it with 'nvme01n/nvme01n1' or such like I see for say sda/sda1,
and
`sudo fdisk -l | grep "nvm"` returns
`Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors`.
In /mnt/nvme I can `touch test`, then `ls` returns `lost+found  test` and `df test`returns `/dev/nvme0n1   479670976 73756 455161508   1% /mnt/nvme`.

So it appears that there are no partitions on device nvme0n1, yet I can read and write files to it. What's going on? Don't we actually need partitions for anything??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can create a filesystem on any block device; as you've shown, that could be the "whole disk" device.  Usually it's a partition, once a label is written to the disk to define the partitions.  One of the other uses of the label is to hold the master boot record, so an unpartitioned/unlabeled disk could never be booted from.  So it's customary, but not required, to always partition/label big disks.  It's interesting that if one tells ZFS to put file system on a whole-disk device, ZFS goes ahead and writes a label (with one big partition) anyway.